# Is the current through the MCP41010 digital potentiometer independent from its supply voltage?

Tags: integrated-circuit, digital-potentiometer

In the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/11195c.pdf) it says that the maximum wiper current is 1mA. Does this mean that regardless of the supply voltage and the set resistance, I can pass a maximum of 1mA through the resistor? Let's say the supply voltage and logic level is 3.3v, and I set the resistor to 7KOhm. Is it OK to pass a 0.7 mA through the resistor, although the voltage drop is greater than the supply voltage?

Answer (score 1):

No, it’s probably not ok. Most digipots will not tolerate more than a few hundred milli volts on the pot pins outside the range of the power supply pins so, if the supply is 0 volts and 3.3 volts, you should not apply voltages less than -0.2 volts or greater than 3.5 volts to the pot pins without referring to the data sheets.

The wiper limit of 1 mA is in addition to the above maximum ratings.

All digipots are not the same so always refer to the actual device’s data sheet.